# tailwindcss alert hovering over fixed nav

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a web app I'm building out in Rails 5, Ruby 2.4. Im using Tailwindcss as my design framework.

I have a hero image (below) in which I'm using a tailwind like alert as a banner to advertise a new web store for merch. It sits exactly where I want it to im the hero, however on page scroll it floats over my fixed nav, and in mobile view with the nav menu dropped down it floats overtop of it blocking the nav view.

Im not too sure how to fix this so it sits behind the nav and dosnt obstruct the nav functionality.

link to site for viewing 
[Loadlead website](http://loadlead.io)

my hero image code:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap sm:block bg-transparent" id="header-hero">
  <div class="container mx-auto">

    /* BANNER THATS CAUSING ISSUES */
    <div class="bg-transparent text-center py-4 lg:px-4">
      <div class="p-2 bg-load-lead-green items-center text-white leading-none lg:rounded-full flex lg:inline-flex opacity-75 border-b-4 border-black md:mt-8">
        <span class="flex rounded-full bg-blue uppercase px-2 py-1 text-xs font-bold mr-3 border-b-2 border-black">New</span>
        <span class="font-semibold mr-2 text-left flex-auto">Pre-order LoadLead gear in our new web store</span>
        <svg class="fill-current opacity-75 h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M12.95 10.707l.707-.707L8 4.343 6.586 5.757 10.828 10l-4.242 4.243L8 15.657l4.95-4.95z"/></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
/* END BANNER */

    <div class="flex py-8 px-4 sm:px-8">
      <div class="w-full py-8">
        <p class="text-4xl text-black font-sans font-bold mb-1">Trucking. Simplified</p>
        <p class="text-xl text-black sm:text-lg mb-6 font-sans font-semibold">Minimize your trucks downtime &amp; keep your loads moving!</p>
        <a class="bg-blue text-white no-underline uppercase text-sm px-4 py-2 rounded-full font-bold hover:bg-blue border border-b-4 border-black hover:border-transparent cursor-not-allowed" href="/#">Take a Tour</a>
        <a class="bg-load-lead-green text-white no-underline uppercase text-sm px-4 py-2 rounded-full font-bold hover:bg-load-lead-green border border-b-4 border-black hover:border-transparent cursor-not-allowed" href="/#">Join the Community</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your hero as relative and the banner as absolute positions.

Comment: Adding some code to your answer, such as an example of the `css` you would use, will improve the quality of your answer.